# TypeORM findby Child Properties of a MongoDB Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typeorm

I have a MongoDB document in the following format. I can verify that it exists in MongoDB using Compass. I'm using TypeORM to make the query, not MondoDB.

```
{
    _id: 'some id'
    user: {
        details: {
            email: "test@test.ch",
            username: "testname"
        },
        status: 'active'
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use TypeORM to find by, say, the email?

I've tried

```
const emailExists = await this.userRepo.findOneBy({
        user: {
            details: {
                email: "test@test.ch"
            }
        }
});
```

but `emailExists` always returns null even though I can validate that it exists in MongoDB.  I've tried other ways to find by `email` using `find`, `findOne`, and more.

How do you find a matching value of a child property, like `email`?  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### MongoDB: Query on Nested Field

To specify a query condition on fields in an embedded/nested document, use dot notation.

- Example: `'field.nestedField'`

> When querying using dot notation:
>
> The field and nested field must be inside quotation marks.

Applying in your code:

```
const emailExists = await this.userRepo.findOneBy({'user.details.email': 'test@test.ch'});
```

##### Reference:

- [MongoDB Official Documentation: Query on Embedded/Nested Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field)

---

**Update:** Looks TypeORM not work well with MongoDB, but you can try use `$match`.

Example:

```
$match : { 'field.nestedField': nestedField }
```

Applying in your code:

```
this.userRepo.findOneBy({$match: { 'user.details.email': 'test@test.ch' }});
```

> If not work maybe try to change TypeORM to Mongoose.

##### Reference:

- https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2483

Comment: Does this also work via typeorm?  I'm getting an error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"user.details.email"' does not exist in type 'FindOptionsWhere<User> | FindOptionsWhere<User>[]'.

Comment: Mongoose it is!  Thank you!